# Drupal 7 - how to set up and translate field collection

Tags: drupal, collections, field, translate, multilingual

I have taxonomy term with field collection field set to unlimited values. FC contains few texfield, textarea and image fields. FC and it's fields are set to be translated by user.
Taxonomy term is localized - all terms are the same for all languages just that they are translated. I have entity translation turned on for taxonomy term and node but not for FC because it trigers notice about not valid base path.

With this configuration: I create term and save it, after initial creation i can add any number of FCs and save them. On translate form I can then add translations for them. And when saved values remain saved for different laguages.

Problem occures when I create a view with relationship to FC, add FC fields and set contextual filter to termID (showing this view via panel on taxonomy terms). Field language stting is set to current user language. On views preview with manually set termID I see proper result for language in url (en/admin/structure/views..) and correct result if I change language prefix. But on term page it doesn't show anything.

I am using latest dev entiy translation an field collection modules. 
I also tried setup with entity translation enabled for FC but again i don't get right output from views.

Where am I doing it wrong? FC setup, multilangual setup or in views. Does anyone have a hint how to make FC translatable?

Answer (score 4):

I retested on clean installation. All this apply for what I described in [#9](http://drupal.org/node/1683784#comment-6421774) . Same result but some new/confirmed observations and possible workaround:

There is a bug in FC when translating fields for the first time values are not properly saved:

- values are saved but when I refresh edit page, fields exist but are
  empty/blank, fields on default language are ok

  - what really happens: when saving translation of FC fields, they are wrongfully linked to default language and not to translated one, also they don't show up when reopening default language so that they could be deleted. This can be bad if you accidentally catch them in a view as I did (for some time this was misleading me because titles were the same).
  - possible workaround: when first translating you have to delete values that are copied from default language and save it, then you can enter translated values
  - ET for FC enabled: same issue and workaround

After creating some content on terms and translating them with workaround, I tried to show them in panels via view.

- I created a panel and set selection to taxonomy vocabulary I am using and under content I created "new custom content" in which I included some substitutions - for FC field %term:field_test_fc (this is my test content)

  - when I change language, values change accordingly to selected language
    substitution renders all fields of FC and shows them in correct language
    this is why this issue is bugging me… it should work on a view too because if term itself can distinguish between different languages of FC fields so can view via panel
- I created view (page) in which I list all FC fields of all terms grouped by term name using relationship of that FC

  - content does change accordingly to the selected language =)
- I created another view (content pane) as above and just added context filter, set it to termID and attach it to panels

  - view shows only FC fields of language that was used last when saving term. This mean that when editing and saving term in default language, view will only show fields of default language. weird :S
- ET for FC enabled: it broke both views (showing fields of all languages everywhere), fixed by adding filter based on FC field: language and setting it to current user language

  - panels view still didn’t work as expected, but I knew that there was a problem with context filter
  - what I had to do is to remove validation criteria from context filter ( termID)

After solving last problem, view for panel is working and viewing term in both languages shows correct (translated) FC fields =).

Hope it helps understanding where problems occur and how to go around them. Fix would be nice though =)

Answer (score 1):

Field Collections as a module has not yet been patched to support multilingual well.  The debate is whether the field collection itself should be set to language-neutral, allowing the underlying fields to be language specific.

However, the field-collection module by itself does not currently support multilingual.  There are a number of patches related to this on Drupal.org, including the following two major patch threads:

https://drupal.org/node/1344672

https://drupal.org/node/1316162

The Lingotek Translation module for Drupal 7 is successful at translating field collections and displaying them because it gets around the limitations of the Field Collection module using a combination of hook_entity_load, hook_entity_update, and a translation process that does not rely on the entity_translation module's UI.